# Convert .docx to HTML using JAVA

Tags: java, apache-tika

I tried converting .doc to HTML by using `WordToHtmlConverter` and it worked perfectly.

But when i tried to convert .docx to HTML, i got stuck with it.

What i tried:

I used the below code to convert .docx to HTML:

The code which i tried from : [How to use Tika's XWPFWordExtractorDecorator class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051183/how-to-use-tikas-xwpfwordextractordecorator-class)

```
        InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(new File("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\filename.docx"));


        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();


        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)
                 SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
        TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        handler.setResult(new StreamResult(sw));


        try {
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
            String xml = sw.toString();
            System.out.print("tika : "+xml); 
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }
```

The output what i got is,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title/>
</head>
<body/>
</html>
```

- Please explain where i gone wrong?
- Is there any better way to convert .docx to html string

Appreciate your help, Thanks

Comment: According to the documentation https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/converter/WordToHtmlConverter.html this API is meant to be used up to Word 2007 when there were only .doc . So it won't work for .docx with this API. Try so save your document in .doc

Comment: @singe31 you dint get my point. I have converted .doc to html by using hwpf converter. But im trying to do it for .docx, is there a way?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/XWPFConverterXHTML

Comment: At their simplest `.docx` files are an archive (you can open them with something like 7zip and view the contents) containing a bunch of XML files. With that in mind, you'd want to use something that can transform the XML into HTML.

Comment: You could also take a look on [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) or any other command line tool from Java. These tasks are not that trivial and I'm not sure if there's a a working API out there for that other than POI ATM.

Comment: i figured it out by using the link :  code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/XWPFConverterXHTML. i'll just post it as answer, it might help someone. Thank you all for your sugesstions.

Comment: You can use docx4j for that, see the example: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutHtml.java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code worked for me to convert .docx to html:

You can also look at the link : [Link to code](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/XWPFConverterXHTML)

```
       //convert .docx to HTML string
        InputStream in= new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(in);


        XHTMLOptions options = XHTMLOptions.create().URIResolver(new FileURIResolver(new File("word/media")));

        OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


        XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
        String html=out.toString();
        System.out.println(html);
```

Comment: Could anyone provide an updated example please? The reference does not work anymore. Thanks.

Comment: I was getting problem using this code, as I was not able to get the jar for
XHTMLOptions, XHTMLConverter and FileURIResolver and then when I searched I got these jars here 
"org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.6.jar", "org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml-1.0.6.jar" and "ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar", if you use these jars you will not get any kind of error with the above code

Comment: @Vipul here you have dependency with it https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml/1.0.6

Comment: Thanks all for saving my time.

Comment: I have followed the above code it's converting docx to html. But i didn't get border styles which are applied in my docx!!. Any idea??????

Comment: Images are not working in my case. Is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make use of Mammoth docx to HTML library.Its a library for displaying doc, docx documents by converting them to html on the browser side as well as can be handled on the backend.

- Library Supports - JavaScript, both the browser and node.js. Available on npm.
  Python. Available on PyPI.
  WordPress.
  Java/JVM. Available on Maven Central.
  .NET. Available on NuGet.
- Link: https://mike.zwobble.org/projects/mammoth/ (Demo and Article)
- Github: https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js