# i want to convert docx to multipage html in java

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, mammoth

i want to convert word document file to Html in java with page separation. it is already working with mammoth in java but output Html comes only one page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert .docx to HTML using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652953/convert-docx-to-html-using-java)

Comment: no iam getting nullpointer exception