# Convert Docx to html using Java

Tags: java, html, docx

I had tried different libraries like **Apache POI**, **Apache Tika**, **Mammoth**, etc and StackOverflow like [Convert .docx to HTML using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652953/convert-docx-to-html-using-java) but none of the given **exact font** and **color** while converting Docx to HTML.

I am able to convert Docx to HTML but the problem is formatting and CSS styles mismatching between Docx and Html.

**Sample input content**:

[image]

Please help me out.

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to use the [Aspose.Words for Java API](https://blog.aspose.com/2020/07/15/word-document-doc-docx-to-html-conversion-using-java/). A few lines of code and you're done.

Comment: Aspose is a paid version, I can't purchase it.

Comment: This could also have been closed because it is a request for a software recommendation.  These are explicitly off-topic.  If you want to understand the downvotes, I suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of question should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @StephenC, I have mentioned what are the library and my problems, I didn't requested not direct software recommendation. Please help me to reopen vote,

Comment: If I thought that your question was suitable for reopening, I would vote.  You need to edit it to make it more suitable for StackOverflow before I will vote to reopen.  Sorry.  The links I provided above should help you figure out what is needed.

Comment: I have edited my question, please check and add if need more edits.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project in GitHub that may suffice your needs: [java-mammoth](https://github.com/mwilliamson/java-mammoth)

I think is a little stable and easy to use, above all it's open-source, many guys use it.

Comment: I tried already, mammoth not support alignment, font-style, and color. See this demo link to check how mammoth support https://mike.zwobble.org/projects/mammoth/