# Is there any way to choose .doc file and extract text from there in android studio java

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a project where there is a feature choose file and extract text from those particularly file anyone can help me I'm developing this app in android studio using java technology

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227236/convert-word-doc-to-html-programmatically-in-java then html to pdf or what you need

Answer (score 0):

First try to convert doc to html then extract text from html.
check this link: [Convert .docx to HTML using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652953/convert-docx-to-html-using-java)

Answer (score -1):

yes you can apache poi jar file in your android studio lib directory

Comment: Please refer to this next time answering a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).